# How to disable Caller id in twilio?

Tags: twilio

In my applicalion, i am using twilio calling api. i am using rest service to make a call it's fine. if any possible to hide a from number to users? i need to block orginal from phone number? thanks in advance.        `        HashMap params = new HashMap();

```
    params.put("From", "+XXXXXXXXXXXXX"); 

    params.put("To", num);
    params.put("Url", Url);


    CallFactory callFactory = account.getCallFactory();


    try {
        Call call = callFactory.create(params);`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately its not possible to hide the [caller ID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids).  You can choose to show either a Twilio phone number or a number you have verified with Twilio.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok thanks.can give phonenumber parameter as dummy number.it's possible?

Comment: The API requires that you provide either a phone number that you have purchased from Twilio, or a phone number that you have verified with Twilio.  You cannot use arbitrary or fake numbers.  Can I ask why you want to hide your number or provide a dummy number?  Maybe there is a better way.