# How to set an outbound number as a unknown CallerId in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am currently developing a phone system using Twilio for a company I work for. For some calls we do not want our outbound number to display to the customer we our calling and instead display "Unknown" or something along them lines is this possible within Twilio?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155406/how-to-disable-caller-id-in-twilio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecorvo has it correct.

An [`OutgoingCallerId`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids) can only be represented by a Twilio number or number you have verified with Twilio.